# ckeditor slow firefox

Tags: html, ckeditor

I have a ckeditor who is very (VERY) slow. 
Does anybody has this problem with a modest amount of html (just 16kb of data!!)

I understand that an editor will get slow with 5mb of data but just 16kb is not so good.
Does anybody have the same problems i am facing ?

It is by the way not a particular browser issue i have tested this in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Would you have an online issue ?

Answer (score 1):

use the php caller instead

Comment: I us ruby, more specifically Ruby on Rails). But i don't even know what php caller is. So I will google maybe it is a solution. Thanxs!

Comment: Ok so it is a ckeditor problem. Has anybody any idea what that problem can be? :) thanxs!

Answer (score 1):

What's the version of CKEditor?

What do you mean with slow?

It takes too long to load or to react to the user actions?

Have you tried to disable the automatic spellchecker (config.scayt_autoStartup = false;)?

Have you modified some code?
Do you have other scripts in the page?
Can you provide a URL to test?...

Comment: ok so i use the latest version (that was the first think i checked) 
With slow i mean not the load time but the responce time of typing
I didn't (yet) disable the spellchecker (is it on by default? ) 

and no i have not modified the code. But i will have a go with the automatic spellchecker! THANXS !

Comment: The latest version has enabled by default the spellchecker and that can cause some slowness depending on the contents.